# Pick one value from multiple value from the combination sql

Tags: sql, join

we have id table as following

```
id  |  newsecid
--- |  ---
1   |  10
2   |  20
3   |  30
```

Single id will have single newsecid

other table is feat

```
id  |  featid
--- |  ---
1   |  5
1   |  6
2   |  2
2   |  4
```

One id can have multiple feat ids

ref table

```
newsecid  |  featid  |  oldsecid
---       |  ---     |  ---
6         |  null    |  2
2         |  null    |  6
3         |  null    |  5  
1         |  NULL    |  1
1         |  5       |  4
16        |  NULL    |  16
16        |  4       |  13
25        |  NULL    |  26
25        |  6       |  25
26        |  NULL    |  26
26        |  6       |  24
```

When there are multiple featids for the same id the we consider them as null to join with the ref tables

For all the newsecids there is no need for the combination of newsecid and featid to get the oldsecid from the ref table because there is always only one value like in the case  of newsecids as 6,2 and 3 with featid as null.

But for only newsecids 1,16,25,26 we have to pick oldsecid from the combination of newsecid and featid  from the ref table as there are 2 values for that.One with null featid and one with some featid value.

The cases where there is no requirement for the combination I am using

```
select c.oldsecid from id i
inner join feat f on i.id=f.id
inner join ref c  on i.newsecid = c.newsecid
```

Using this I am getting oldsecid 2,6,5 from the ref table since there is only one value.

For the cases 1,16,25,26 using the above query I am getting random oldsecid .In this I need that oldsecid where featid is not null.

We can hardcode the condition of newsecid for 1,16,25,26 as I dont have only these cases only.

Any help

Comment: `Id` is a horrible table name...

Comment: @jarlh : Just for an example

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding , Try:

```
select c.oldsecid from id i
inner join feat f on i.id=f.id
inner join ref c  on i.newsecid = c.newsecid
Inner join( select newSecId,count(*)  as newSecIdCount from ref group by newSecId) r on r.newSecId=i.newSecId

Where (r.newSecIdCount=1 or c.feetid is not null)
```